# Android + Android Studio: cannot resolve method settext(java.lang.string)

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to be able to set the text of buttons using the strings xml file. I have this code;

```
Button playVid = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.vidbutton1);
playVid.SetText(this.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.play_video));
```

And this xml

```
<string name="play_video">Play Video</string>
```

But I get the compile

> error: cannot resolve method settext(java.lang.string)

I am using Android Studio. Everywhere I have read suggest that you can use strings to set text (makes sense, right?), so I am very confused.

This also will not work:

```
playVid.SetText("Test");
```

Bug in AS?

Comment: the error message does not match your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind your casing. Use `setText()` instead of `SetText()`.

Also there's an overload `setText(int)` that takes in a resource id. You can use it to set a value from resources without using `getString()` to obtain it yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

Methods in Java usually start with a lower-case letter. Maybe that's what your problem is here.

Try `playVid.setText("Test");` instead of `playVid.SetText("Test");`

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.some_button);
button.setText(R.string.hello_world);
```

Make sure you imports are correct ;)